# An SSL error has occurred, but data is received

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ssl, alamofire

I tried many options including those provided on stackoverflow and nothing helps. If i don't enter in my application during one hour or more i receive ssl error and my method doesn't execute.

```
        test.getModelFromQuarter { (result) in
        if result {
            print("*********SUCCESS********")

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.setChart(dataPoints: self.test.getDataPoint(for: .week), values: self.test.getDefaultCCY(from: .week)!.values)

                self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()

                self.currencyBanner.text = "НБУ - \(self.test.getDefaultCCY(from: .week)!.values.last!) \(self.test.getDefaultCCY(from: .week)!.ccy)"

                self.setComparingImage(firstValue: (self.test.getDefaultCCY(from: .week)?.values.last)!, secondValue: (self.test.getDefaultCCY(from: .week)?.values.dropLast().last)!)
            }
        }
```

This is the method with issue.

```
    func load(url: String, handler: @escaping ([CCYModel]) -> Void) {
    var ccyModels: [CCYModel] = []

    Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON { (response) in
        if response.result.isSuccess {
            if let json = try? JSON(response.result.value!) {

                if let array = json.array {
                    for json in array {
                        let model = CCYModel(ccy: json["cc"].stringValue, rate: json["rate"].doubleValue)
                        ccyModels.append(model)
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            print("*************************")
            print("Fetching currencies error \(response.result.error)")
            print("*************************")
        }

        handler(ccyModels)
    }
}
```

This can be fixed by restarting application or by "reloading ui" which means that **the data from the site is successfully loaded**.

This is my plist where i tried to fix the problem.

```
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsForMedia</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsUsageDescription</key>
    <dict/>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
        <string>TLSv1.2</string>
        <key>https://bank.gov.ua/</key>
        <dict/>
    </dict>
    <key>NSTemporaryExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
    <false/>
</dict>
```

It shows the xcode console when bug occurs:

```
> 2020-01-29 18:07:59.434236+0200 CurrencyInfo[28221:10222320] []
> nw_socket_handle_socket_event [C2.1:3] Socket SO_ERROR [54: Connection
> reset by peer] 2020-01-29 18:07:59.444060+0200
> CurrencyInfo[28221:10222320] Connection 2: received failure
> notification 2020-01-29 18:07:59.444610+0200
> CurrencyInfo[28221:10222320] Connection 2: failed to connect 3:-9816,
> reason -1 2020-01-29 18:07:59.444619+0200 CurrencyInfo[28221:10222320]
> Connection 2: encountered error(3:-9816) 2020-01-29
> 18:07:59.445001+0200 CurrencyInfo[28221:10222320] Task
> <89311F11-5FE1-4BD4-9792-82C796CBE14F>.<2> HTTP load failed, 0/0 bytes
> (error code: -1200 [3:-9816]) 2020-01-29 18:07:59.456604+0200
> CurrencyInfo[28221:10222320] Task
> <89311F11-5FE1-4BD4-9792-82C796CBE14F>.<2> finished with error [-1200]
> Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1200 "An SSL error has occurred
> and a secure connection to the server cannot be made."
> UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://bank.gov.ua/NBUStatService/v1/statdirectory/exchange?date=20200129&json,
> NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server
> anyway?, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3,
> _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <89311F11-5FE1-4BD4-9792-82C796CBE14F>.<2>,
> _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
>     "LocalDataTask <89311F11-5FE1-4BD4-9792-82C796CBE14F>.<2>" ), NSLocalizedDescription=An SSL error has occurred and a secure
> connection to the server cannot be made.,
> NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://bank.gov.ua/NBUStatService/v1/statdirectory/exchange?date=20200129&json,
> NSUnderlyingError=0x2801a03c0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork
> Code=-1200 "(null)"
> UserInfo={_kCFStreamPropertySSLClientCertificateState=0,
> _kCFNetworkCFStreamSSLErrorOriginalValue=-9816, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9816}}, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9816}
> ************************* Fetching currencies error Optional(Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1200 "An SSL error has occurred and a
> secure connection to the server cannot be made."
> UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://bank.gov.ua/NBUStatService/v1/statdirectory/exchange?date=20200129&json,
> NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server
> anyway?, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3,
> _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <89311F11-5FE1-4BD4-9792-82C796CBE14F>.<2>,
> _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
>     "LocalDataTask <89311F11-5FE1-4BD4-9792-82C796CBE14F>.<2>" ), NSLocalizedDescription=An SSL error has occurred and a secure
> connection to the server cannot be made.,
> NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://bank.gov.ua/NBUStatService/v1/statdirectory/exchange?date=20200129&json,
> NSUnderlyingError=0x2801a03c0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork
> Code=-1200 "(null)"
> UserInfo={_kCFStreamPropertySSLClientCertificateState=0,
> _kCFNetworkCFStreamSSLErrorOriginalValue=-9816, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9816}}, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9816})
> *************************
```

I also checked with `nscurl --ats-diagnostics --verbose`

```
>  ~ % nscurl --ats-diagnostics --verbose https://bank.gov.ua Starting
> ATS Diagnostics
> 
> Configuring ATS Info.plist keys and displaying the result of HTTPS
> loads to https://bank.gov.ua. A test will "PASS" if
> URLSession:task:didCompleteWithError: returns a nil error.
> ================================================================================
> 
> Default ATS Secure Connection
> --- ATS Default Connection ATS Dictionary: { } Result : PASS
> ---
> 
> ================================================================================
> 
> Allowing Arbitrary Loads
> 
> --- Allow All Loads ATS Dictionary: {
>     NSAllowsArbitraryLoads = true; } Result : PASS
> ---
> 
> ================================================================================
> 
> Configuring TLS exceptions for bank.gov.ua
> 
> --- TLSv1.3 ATS Dictionary: {
>     NSExceptionDomains =     {
>         "bank.gov.ua" =         {
>             NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion = "TLSv1.3";
>         };
>     }; } Result : FAIL Error : Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1200 "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the
> server cannot be made."
> UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://bank.gov.ua/,
> NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server
> anyway?, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3,
> _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <1BDB6BF8-A49A-44D9-93B9-A28E86DF7CA9>.<1>,
> _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
>     "LocalDataTask <1BDB6BF8-A49A-44D9-93B9-A28E86DF7CA9>.<1>" ), NSLocalizedDescription=An SSL error has occurred and a secure
> connection to the server cannot be made.,
> NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://bank.gov.ua/,
> NSUnderlyingError=0x7f8878428810 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork
> Code=-1200 "(null)"
> UserInfo={_kCFStreamPropertySSLClientCertificateState=0,
> _kCFNetworkCFStreamSSLErrorOriginalValue=-9858, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9858}}, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9858}
> ---
> 
> --- TLSv1.2 ATS Dictionary: {
>     NSExceptionDomains =     {
>         "bank.gov.ua" =         {
>             NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion = "TLSv1.2";
>         };
>     }; } Result : PASS
> ---
> 
> --- TLSv1.1 ATS Dictionary: {
>     NSExceptionDomains =     {
>         "bank.gov.ua" =         {
>             NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion = "TLSv1.1";
>         };
>     }; } Result : PASS
> ---
> 
> --- TLSv1.0 ATS Dictionary: {
>     NSExceptionDomains =     {
>         "bank.gov.ua" =         {
>             NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion = "TLSv1.0";
>         };
>     }; } Result : PASS
> ---
> 
> ================================================================================
> 
> Configuring PFS exceptions for bank.gov.ua
> 
> --- Disabling Perfect Forward Secrecy ATS Dictionary: {
>     NSExceptionDomains =     {
>         "bank.gov.ua" =         {
>             NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy = false;
>         };
>     }; } Result : PASS
> ---
> 
> ================================================================================
> 
> Configuring PFS exceptions and allowing insecure HTTP for bank.gov.ua
> 
> --- Disabling Perfect Forward Secrecy and Allowing Insecure HTTP ATS Dictionary: {
>     NSExceptionDomains =     {
>         "bank.gov.ua" =         {
>             NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads = true;
>             NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy = false;
>         };
>     }; } Result : PASS
> ---
> 
> ================================================================================
> 
> Configuring TLS exceptions with PFS disabled for bank.gov.ua
> 
> --- TLSv1.3 with PFS disabled ATS Dictionary: {
>     NSExceptionDomains =     {
>         "bank.gov.ua" =         {
>             NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion = "TLSv1.3";
>             NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy = false;
>         };
>     }; } Result : FAIL Error : Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1200 "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the
> server cannot be made."
> UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://bank.gov.ua/,
> NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server
> anyway?, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3,
> _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <AA01562F-24EA-4DC9-BCF7-6E9D625D9361>.<1>,
> _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
>     "LocalDataTask <AA01562F-24EA-4DC9-BCF7-6E9D625D9361>.<1>" ), NSLocalizedDescription=An SSL error has occurred and a secure
> connection to the server cannot be made.,
> NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://bank.gov.ua/,
> NSUnderlyingError=0x7f887a800470 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork
> Code=-1200 "(null)"
> UserInfo={_kCFStreamPropertySSLClientCertificateState=0,
> _kCFNetworkCFStreamSSLErrorOriginalValue=-9858, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9858}}, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9858}
> ---
> 
> --- TLSv1.2 with PFS disabled ATS Dictionary: {
>     NSExceptionDomains =     {
>         "bank.gov.ua" =         {
>             NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion = "TLSv1.2";
>             NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy = false;
>         };
>     }; } Result : PASS
> ---
> 
> --- TLSv1.1 with PFS disabled ATS Dictionary: {
>     NSExceptionDomains =     {
>         "bank.gov.ua" =         {
>             NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion = "TLSv1.1";
>             NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy = false;
>         };
>     }; } Result : PASS
> ---
> 
> --- TLSv1.0 with PFS disabled ATS Dictionary: {
>     NSExceptionDomains =     {
>         "bank.gov.ua" =         {
>             NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion = "TLSv1.0";
>             NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy = false;
>         };
>     }; } Result : PASS
> ---
> 
> ================================================================================
> 
> Configuring TLS exceptions with PFS disabled and insecure HTTP allowed
> for bank.gov.ua
> 
> --- TLSv1.3 with PFS disabled and insecure HTTP allowed ATS Dictionary: {
>     NSExceptionDomains =     {
>         "bank.gov.ua" =         {
>             NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads = true;
>             NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion = "TLSv1.3";
>             NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy = false;
>         };
>     }; } Result : FAIL Error : Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1200 "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the
> server cannot be made."
> UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://bank.gov.ua/,
> NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server
> anyway?, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3,
> _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <BDF920C9-E44E-4DCD-BED7-94274E454AF4>.<1>,
> _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
>     "LocalDataTask <BDF920C9-E44E-4DCD-BED7-94274E454AF4>.<1>" ), NSLocalizedDescription=An SSL error has occurred and a secure
> connection to the server cannot be made.,
> NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://bank.gov.ua/,
> NSUnderlyingError=0x7f887a800390 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork
> Code=-1200 "(null)"
> UserInfo={_kCFStreamPropertySSLClientCertificateState=0,
> _kCFNetworkCFStreamSSLErrorOriginalValue=-9858, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9858}}, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9858}
> ---
> 
> --- TLSv1.2 with PFS disabled and insecure HTTP allowed ATS Dictionary: {
>     NSExceptionDomains =     {
>         "bank.gov.ua" =         {
>             NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads = true;
>             NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion = "TLSv1.2";
>             NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy = false;
>         };
>     }; } Result : PASS
> ---
> 
> --- TLSv1.1 with PFS disabled and insecure HTTP allowed ATS Dictionary: {
>     NSExceptionDomains =     {
>         "bank.gov.ua" =         {
>             NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads = true;
>             NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion = "TLSv1.1";
>             NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy = false;
>         };
>     }; } Result : PASS
> ---
> 
> --- TLSv1.0 with PFS disabled and insecure HTTP allowed ATS Dictionary: {
>     NSExceptionDomains =     {
>         "bank.gov.ua" =         {
>             NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads = true;
>             NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion = "TLSv1.0";
>             NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy = false;
>         };
>     }; } Result : PASS
> ---
> 
> ============================================================================
```

Is it possible for xcode to ignoring this error? Because my app working fine, data is loaded. Just method in viewDidLoad sometimes doesn't load ui.

Comment: Your `nscurl` results seem to indicate that you don't need any ATS options for that domain, just that it doesn't support TLSv1.3 only. External testing verifies the same. So are you perhaps behind a proxy?